# Convert jison object back to string

Tags: jison

So I have created a .jison file for a search query language that is basically a subset of the SQL where statement.  That file can be viewed here:

https://gist.github.com/ryanzec/7d1c8100d1b5f03c0a17

Now it works as I expect it to when converting a string into the JSON object.  Now I have read the documentation and can't find anything on this but it is possible to take the outputted JSON object and easily compile that back into the string or do I have to manually write that process for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jison does not have any facilities to automatically perform a transformation which is the reverse of the one you've specified to convert your input to your output. So you have to write the reverse transformation yourself.